# SSIS package - How to rename pivoted columns

Tags: ssis, business-intelligence

I'm new to SSIS and just created a simple package taking input from a source file then pivot it and insert into the database. It works well for me.

I am aware that I can provide an alias name for each column under Pivot > Advance Editor > Input and Output Properties > Pivot Default Output > Output Columns > Set the "Name" property to whatever I want. I want to ask if there is away to rename the pivoted column programmatically? I have about 100 columns and thought it is more effective to do this in code but not sure how. I tried to add a script component but not able to get to the "Name" property... My end goal is to remove the "C_" from the auto generated pivot column names. This way when I'm inserting the record to the db, it can auto map for me.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your goal "rename columns dynamically in package itself" contradicts to basic SSIS approach, which is "**fix metadata, including column type and name, at design phase, and reuse at runtime**". So, no script component can rename your columns.
You can use BIML or EzAPI/Microsoft SSIS DLLs to *generate package* based on your metadata; but once you design it, the package metadata including column names is fixed.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out BIML/AzAPI. In fact the column names are actually in good shape up until I pivot them, then SSIS adds the "C_" to each column name.